# Difference between level = NOTSET and propagate

Tags: python, logging

If I have a logger that's directly under root, and that I set its level to NOTSET while propagate = False. What would happen ?
The doc is unclear to me :

> When a logger is created, the level is set to NOTSET (which causes all messages to be processed when the logger is the root logger, or delegation to the parent when the logger is a non-root logger)

I don't know if that means that the root logger is used instead of the NOTSET one or just that the root  logger level is inherited

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I found this in the doc

> The level and handlers entries are interpreted as for the root logger, except that if a non-root logger’s level is specified as NOTSET, the system consults loggers higher up the hierarchy to determine the effective level of the logger.

So I guess That the NOTSET level only makes the logger inherit its parent level.